# UICollectionviewCell: compute perfect cellsize

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm having a UICollectionView that gets populated with different numbers of cells.
The cells should use the available space as perfect as it is possible. For this I compute the available space per cell.

The available space should be computed when the view initializes. Each cell has a spacing of 2pt to everything. Currently I have hard code the space of navigationbar and statusbar with 64pt, which is not future proof.

With the code below everything is working in Simulator, but not on real hardware (iPhone5s): On my physical iPhone the height is not computed correctly and and an gap about 30pt appears between the last row and the bottom of the collection view.

Any idea how to improve the code?

```
private func computeCellSizes(var size :CGSize){

        if(size == CGSizeZero){
            size = self.collectionView!.frame.size
        }

        self.numberOfRows  = Int(size.width / 103)

        //spacing of 2 points between each cell
        let availableWidth = size.width - CGFloat((self.numberOfRows + 1)  * 2)
        let cellWidth = availableWidth / CGFloat(numberOfRows)

        self.numberOfColumns = Int(size.height / (cellWidth * 1.3))
        //spacing of 2 points between each cell, minus navigationcontroller height
        let availableHeight = size.height - CGFloat((numberOfColumns + 1)  * 2) - 64
        let cellHeight = availableHeight / CGFloat(numberOfColumns)

        let cellSize =  CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellHeight)

        self.cachedSizes.setObject(NSValue(CGSize: cellSize), forKey: size.width)
    }
```

Comment: When asking for help with code, please explain *how* what you've got is failing. *How* does your code fail on "real hardware"?

Comment: thanks for your comment - I added this.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this
(in UICollectionViewController implementation):

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10); //spacing on margins (top, left, bottom, right)
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake((self.view.frame.size.width - 40)/3, 100.0); // I show 3 cell for one row (-40 - spaces between cells and screen sides)
}
```

Comment: this doesn't answer my question, because it ignores different devices

Comment: @netshark1000 what do you mean 'it ignores different devices'? You got view.frame size and calculate the best size of cells for current view.frame. Write this size in method `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` and all will be fine.